# Unable to authenticate, need: Bearer authorization for mac

Tags: azure, npm-install

I am trying to install azure npm package and getting following error message

> Unable to authenticate, need: Bearer
> authorization_uri=https://login.windows.net/e9eaca6f-eb13-43c6-9284-85cc1a244bfe,
> Basic realm="https://pkgsprodeus21.pkgs.visualstudio.com/",
> TFS-Federated

Even i follow the official documentations https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/get-started-npm?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows

and my .npm file details is below

```
registry=https://{orgname}.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/{npmname}/npm/registry/
always-auth=true

; begin auth token
//pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/{npmname}/npm/registry/:username={username}
//pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/{npmname}/npm/registry/:_password={password}
//{orgname}.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/{npmname}/npm/registry/:email=npm requires email to be set but doesn't use the value
//pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/{npmname}/npm/:username={username}
//pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/{npmname}/npm/:_password={password}
//pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/{npmname}/npm/:email=npm requires email to be set but doesn't use the value
; end auth token
```

Comment: Found any solution? I've the same problem

Comment: Hello @AlessioBreviglieri no need to do anything inside your project repo's. Follow this documentation and your .npmrc file at root to your computer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/npm/npmrc?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows.